# Updated win10 BSOD randomly, continues BSOD after fresh reinstall with factory drivers

Tags: windows-10, bsod

Half a year ago I purchased Ryzen 5 3600 on ASUS Prime A520m-k motherboard with 2x16 GB ddr4 and Radeon 550/550 graphics. After updating system periodically and drivers it started BSODing randomly, RAM passed the test, PSU is ok, motherboard is ok, graphics also .Fresh reinstall, OS reinstall and rolling back drivers helped, but not significantly. I Still have BSOD that happen 3-4 times a day and I've noticed they are similar¸ and pointing to ntoskrnl.exe and 3fbca0 address. ( also worth mentioning that downclocking did not help).

BSOD happens randomly, during gaming, watching video, copying files, or just idling.

Here's the first column from BSV

ntoskrnl.exe    ntoskrnl.exe+28279d fffff805`2f200000   fffff805`30246000   0x01046000  0xf71f414a  5/20/2101 10:24:42 AM   Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    NT Kernel & System  10.0.19041.2965 (WinBuild.160101.0800)  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe

3 last dump files have been uploaded here

https://easyupload.io/rmu17h

Please do not tell me to update the drivers or to switch to win11 :D

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I have used Blue Screen View. If i put the main error string into Bing AI, one of the prime outputs is to update drivers. What would you like to hear instead?

Comment: Lol, thanks John :)

Comment: Maybe contact ASUS Support to see if hey have better drivers.

Comment: when you say "ram passed the test", exactly what test are you referring to?

Comment: memtest86 and i've taken them out,one by one, swapped them.

Comment: Fyi: the most important info on a BSOD is the five hex numbers. Without them, all other information is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

It was bloody Avast AV. Two weeks of testing and 100 dump files analyzed.
I hope this message helps someone.
Edit--
While researching this issue I have tried changing the hardware, setup configuration, uninstalled third party software that might cause the issue and driver rollback, with no effect. Upon fresh win install with measures to prevent updates without my explicit consent ( MS graphic driver forced update over AMD drivers on few occasions, it alerted me when Adrenaline CTD) it had continued to BSOD.A bunch of minidumps later, with driver verifier and a correspondence with a MS help it became clear that avast might be an issue. After uninstalling it my hourly BSOD went away. System instability started appearing after i rolled back GPU drivers from MS to AMD ones.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).